# groups: command not found

Tags: linux

I'm getting the following error after logging in:

```
Last login: Thu May 30 15:25:49 2013 from 
-bash: groups: command not found

xxx@Dogbert:~$ /usr/bin/groups
-bash: /usr/bin/groups: Permission denied

xxx@Dogbert:~# su -

root@Dogbert:~# ls -la /usr/bin/groups 

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26180 Mai 28 22:21 /usr/bin/groups
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

1 easy possibility (before further infos from you):

- At the point where your login script(s) uses "groups" (without saying "/usr/bin/groups"), the current $PATH doesn't yet contain /usr/bin ?